# Calculate field management not working within customized Python tool in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator, python-toolbox

I am trying to make a custom made Python Script tool which I would like to use in Model builder. I am using the arcpy.Calulate_field_management function (simple reclass function as an example), but it seems not be working properly. Please note that when I run this script on its own through a Python editor (IDLE), the script works fine. After adjusting it to make it work for a custom Python Script tool, the script stops when it is going to calculate the field.

This is the script which I use for my tool with a comment where it stops. The arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) refers to the table which you can find in the picture below.

```
import arcpy
try:
    fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
    arcpy.AddMessage("Hi Jelle, your script is starting now...")    
    def calc_value(orig_field):
        if (orig_field == "R<10_min"):
            return "1"
        elif (orig_field == "R_10-20_min"):
            return "2"
        elif (orig_field == "R_30+"):
            return "3"
    def calc_field():
        arcpy.AddMessage("Calculating field management has started, Jelle")
        reclass_field = "Reclass_SA_All"
        ##HERE is WHERE PYTHON SCRIPT TOOL STOPS
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, reclass_field, "calc_value(!SA_All!)", "PYTHON_9.3")
        arcpy.AddMessage("Reclass Field calculation is done, Jelle.")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Starting calc_field function, Jelle...")
    calc_field()
    arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, fc)       
except:
    arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Here is a picture of the table which I am trying to edit together with the customized script tool window when it is finished running. I have added customized messages in my script to find out where the script stops running.

[image]

I have the feeling I am doing a basic error which stops the scripts from running the calculate_field_management within my tool. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? AM i right if I say the calculate_field_management cannot refer to another function within my expression? This does work when I run the script on its own through a Python editor (IDLE).

Comment: Try sys.argv[1] instead of GetParameterAsText(0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to calculate a field using complex logic when you're already using Python is to do it with an [`UpdateCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000) instead of the Calculate Field tool. (As @FaridCher's answer shows, you end up defining a Python function in a string, which makes it difficult to read, as well as to write.)

In your code, I would replace

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, reclass_field, "calc_value(!SA_All!)", "PYTHON_9.3")
```

with

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [reclass_field, 'SA_All']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = calc_value(row[1])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Note: this method uses the `UpdateCursor` from `arcpy`'s "Data Access" (`da`) module. If you have ArcGIS 10.0 or earlier, you will have to use the [regular cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Cursor/018z0000009r000000/).

Comment: thank you for this tip. My code is a little more complex than this example I use here and I agree with you that using long strings as codeblocks makes it a little hard to read and write. In my current code, I have more fields within the the calc_value function. How would I call these fields within the for row loop?

Comment: In the list of fieldnames being supplied to the `UpdateCursor`, just add the other fieldnames you want from the feature class, then add them as additional parameters for `calc_value` with `row[2]`, `row[3]`, etc. The items in `row` are ordered the same as the fieldnames in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using if-elif statements, just reclassify using a one-liner expression with a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
{"R<10_min": "1", "R_10-20_min": "2", "R_30+": "3"}.get(!SA_All!, "0")
```

which you can put the CalculateField_management function:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(
    fc, reclass_field,
    '''{"R<10_min": "1", "R_10-20_min": "2", "R_30+": "3"}.get(!SA_All!, "0")''',
    "PYTHON_9.3")
```